# What is the reason I got the unit test error?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, unit-testing

```js
function generateHashtag(str) {
    if (str.trim().length > 0 && str.trim().length < 140) {
        return '#' + str.split(' ').map((word) => word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1, word.length)).join('')
    } else
        return false;
}
```

Should return false if the final word is longer than 140 .
Only gives error in this test :

```
Test.assertEquals(generateHashtag("code" + " ".repeat(140) + "wars"), "#CodeWars")
Expected: '#CodeWars', instead got: false
```

Comment: JavaScript's [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) operator removes spaces from the *ends* of the provided string, not from the middle.

Comment: I get same error with replace method

Comment: Please update your question to include that code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the spaces from the middle of the string as well (easy with `replace` and a regex):

```js
function generateHashtag(str) {
  const removedWhitespace = str.replace(/ /g, '');
  if (removedWhitespace.length > 0 && removedWhitespace.length < 140) {
    return '#' + str.split(' ').map((word) => word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1, word.length)).join('')
  } else
    return false;
}

console.log(generateHashtag("code" + " ".repeat(140) + "wars"));
```